# I'm trying to display name on profile user but having errors why?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, backend, display

I followed some tutos and I add user on firestore successly but I can't print this user on the profile page when the current user is logging because `doc.` is underlined in red in my backend, they say : The getter 'doc' isn't defined for the type 'DocumentSnapshot<Object?>'.

This is my entire backend

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

Future<void> userSetup(String displayName) async {
  CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users');
  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  String uid = auth.currentUser!.uid.toString();
  users.add({'displayName': displayName, 'uid' : uid });
  final result = await users.doc(uid).get();
  return result.doc.data()['displayName'];
}
```

Plus I'm having a error too in my front end but I think it's because the backend wrond initialized or just a code wrote.

So this is my front end code:
(userId is red underlined because it's undefined and my [] operators too),

hope you help me !

```
 FutureBuilder(
              future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('users')
            .doc('uid')
            .get(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                  return Text(snapshot.data['displayName'],
                  );
                } else {
                  return Text("Loading...");
```

**I edited**

```
FutureBuilder(
              future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('users')
            .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
            .get(), 
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData)
                  return Text("Loading...");
                if (snapshot.data == null) {
                  print('Document does not exist on the database');
                }else{
                  return Text("Researching data...");
                }
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                  var name = snapshot.data as DocumentSnapshot;
                  return Text(name['displayName'],
                  );
                } else {
                  return Text("Loading..");
                }
              },
            )
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not specifying the document ID when creating user, so then, is created unique ID for your user document, and you can't access the document by user ID. And you should also await the creating process. The solution is easy, just specify the document ID when creating user:

```
Future<void> userSetup(String displayName) async {
  CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users');
  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  String uid = auth.currentUser!.uid.toString();
  await users.doc(uid).set({'displayName': displayName, 'uid': uid });
  final result = await users.doc(uid).get();
  final data = result.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
  return data['displayName'];
}
```

Hope it works!

Comment: I think my code is better like that but I'm still having error at `doc.` : The getter 'doc' isn't defined for the type 'DocumentSnapshot<Object?>'.  Try importing the library that defines 'doc', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'doc'.

Comment: Oh yes, I see that. It throwing an error because you already have the document, so do not need to call *data()*, you can just grab your data. I will edit my answer, hope it will work now"

Comment: Thank you I have no more error in my backend! Should I edit my frontend too ? Because I have this error : The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.  Try making the call conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!'). I tried many things without success... **I've updated  my front end**

Comment: Where exactly do you have that error? in *userSetup*? On the last line? And what do you mean with the front-end? The future builder? (Btw, in the future builder, you have *.doc('uid')* that will not work, you should pass real user id.

Comment: Look at my code I edited with real user data, all is working until the check if snapshot data is null or exist and it returns to me 'Document does not exist on the database'